# PHP - SQL - intval don't work - mistake

Tags: php, mysql, insert

So I'm new, so I'm not so good. 
So sry for my bad english, but I help you can me help!

This is my Code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO bestellung (userID, name, email, item, menge, total)
VALUES (" . intval($row['userID'],'".$_POST["name"]."','".$_POST["email"]."','".$_POST["item"]."','".$_POST["menge"]."','".$_POST["total"]."')";
```

This is not the full CODE!
There is a mistake in invtal, but I don't know what for a mistake!

So I help you can help me! 
Thanks.

Comment: There's quite a bit more that's wrong. I take it you're using regular Notepad so you don't see the errors :) but take a look at what SO's highlighter shows :>

Comment: Yes I work with Notpad, this is the best program for me! And it is free :D

Comment: Do you see the mistake? What is there wrong with intval?

Comment: `intval($row['userID']` should be `intval($row['userID'])` - you didn't close it with `)`. After this, you'll get more errors. I won't guide you character by character, so I suggest you learn the syntax completely or try to figure out where you went wrong. Also, download Notepad++. It's free, it's notepad and it can highlight PHP code so you can spot errors faster. Good luck.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections with this code. You should be using parameterized queries. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 5):

You said in a comment that you're using PDO. This gives you a way to write the code more easily, to avoid frustrating problems with balanced quotes and parentheses.

Here's how I would write this code:

```
$paramDefaults = array("userID"=>null, "name"=>null, "email"=>null,
    "item"=>null, "menge"=>null, "total"=>null);
$params = array_merge($paramDefaults, array_intersect_key($_POST, $paramDefaults));

$sql = "INSERT INTO bestellung SET userID = :userID, name = :name,
    email = :email, item = :item, menge = :menge, total = :total";    
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

See how much easier this is? No need to strain your eyes staring at quotes-within-quotes. No need to think about interpolating unsafe post variables into your SQL query.

You could even set up the `$paramDefaults` array with non-null values so if the web request is missing one of the parameters, your INSERT won't break.

Comment: While this is indeed the best way to motivate OP to use PDO, it would be awesome if you could include the `$pdo` assignment statement. (Just the absence of the definition can be a deterrent and might cause OP to prefer the second answer.)

Comment: @adeelx, the OP said in a comment on msantos' answer that they're already using PDO.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close parenthesis `intval($row['userID']`.See the fix below:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO bestellung (userID, name, email, item, menge, total)
VALUES (" .intval($row['userID']),'".$_POST["name"]."','".$_POST["email"]."','".$_POST["item"]."','".$_POST["menge"]."','".$_POST["total"]."')";
```

**EDIT 1**: One more thing.Use sql prepared statement.It will avoid sql injection:

**EDIT 2**: See the parametrized sql code below:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=****_kevin",$username,$password);

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line


$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO bestellung (name, email, item, menge, total)
VALUES (:name,:email,:item,:menge,:total)");

    $stmt->execute(array('name' => $_POST['name'],
                         'email' => $_POST['email'],
                         'item'=> $_POST['item'],
                         'menge'=> $_POST['menge'],
                         'total'=> $_POST['total']));

    $dbh = null;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
   }
```

Comment: Have you enabled the ini_set("display_errors",1) or got message error on the screen?

Comment: I have this : <?php
echo ini_get('display_errors');

if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}

echo ini_get('display_errors');
?>

Comment: But there aren't Errors.

Comment: Are you using mysqli or pdo extension?

Comment: With pdo you can avoid sql injection

Comment: All of the SQL is invalid, the concatenation is wrong. Please don't have the OP provide all their code when they provided an MVCE as is expected.

Comment: I requested the full code, because i wanted to analyse what is happening.

Comment: The issue is present in provided MVCE and in your answer. `,'".$_POST["name"]."'`. Also placeholders should match the bound name, auto colon appending is not documented and may be removed.

Comment: @chris85 I doubt auto colon appending will be removed. It was *added* since the early days of PDO, and it's a good idea to keep it. Removing it would break lots of PHP code for no good reason.

Comment: @BillKarwin I've seen varying discussions on the topic. I prefer to stick with the documented approach. I agree I don't see why they would remove it since they added it in. I'll start a bounty on one of the other threads, see if there is a primary reference on the topic.